# How do I create something that I can use to access class instances later in my programming?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I'm a beginning programmer in high school who is interested in computer science. I've been teaching myself to program with Python using Mike Dawson's book, *Learning to program for the absolute beginner with Python, 3rd Edition*. I'm writing a program to practice my newly acquired knowledge of OOP. The program simulates a bank in which a player can open bank accounts, withdraw/deposit cash, get exchange rates, transfer money from one account to another, and other features. I am having severe trouble with the program, as the main part of the program that simulates the fact that there are multiple accessible accounts that a user can access. I'm now sure how or if it is the way I should be doing things, but I tried writing a class attribute that is an empty list called all_accounts. Each time an account is instantiated, the instance is appended to the list. When a player chooses a menu option such as withdrawing/depositing cash, I want the instance in the list to be accessed so that the object's attributes (such as balance) can be modified. I have no idea how to do this and I've been searching for an answer for about 3 days now without finding anything. Keep in mind, I'm a beginner programmer, so my code will probably be considered poorly written. I'll post the entire code below, as I feel it is necessary that people get a complete feel of how the code works and functions. Also, feel free to notify me of anything else in my code that isn't right or that I could be doing better. I'm always open to learning.

```
class Account(object):
    """An interactive bank account"""
    wallet = 0
    all_accounts = []

    # initial
    def __init__(self, ID, bal):
        self.ID = ID
        self.bal = bal
        print("A new account has been opened!")
        Account.all_accounts.append(self)                       

    def withdraw(self, w_input):
        if w_input < self.bal  or w_input == 0:
            print("That is not a valid amount. Sending you back to menu.\n")
            Menu()
        else:
            self.bal = self.bal - w_input
            print("You withdrew $" + str(w_input) + ".\n")
            wallet += w_input
            print("You wallet now contains $" + Account.wallet)
            Menu()

    def deposit(self):
        # Whatever



def Menu():
    print(
        """
0 - Leave the Virtual Bank
1 - Open a new account
2 - Withdraw money
3 - Deposit money
4 - Transfer money from one account to another
5 - Get exchange rates(Euro, Franc, Pounds, Yuan, Yen)
"""
        ) # Add more if necessary
    choice = input("What would you like to do?: ")
    while choice != "0":
        if choice == "1":
            account_name = input("What is your account's ID?: ")
            account_bal = float(input("How much money would you like to put into the account?(USD): "))
            account_name = Account(ID = account_name, bal = account_bal)
            Menu()

        elif choice == "2":
            account_choice = input("What is your account ID?: ")
            if account_choice in instance.Account.all_account:
                withdraw_choice = input("How much money would you like to withdraw?: ")
                account_choice.withdraw(w_input = withdraw_choice)
            else:
                print("Nope.")



    if choice == "0":
        print("\nThank you for visiting the virtual bank!")
        input("Press the [ENTER] key to exit the program.")


Menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to isolate the calling code from the inner workings of your class.  Having the `Menu()` function check the list holding all the accounts directly is inflexible and will cause problems later on (what if you swap out the list for database storage?)

Instead, something like an `AccountManager` class may be a better idea:

```
class AccountManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.accounts = []

    def create_account(self, id, balance):
        # You may want to check for uniqueness of id's here as well
        account = Account(id, balance)
        self.accounts.append(account)

    def get_account(self, id):
        for account in self.accounts:
            if account.id == id:
                return account
        return None # or a default value, or raise an exception
```

Now the calling code just has to tell `AccountManager` to create and retrieve accounts, and no longer cares how they're stored.

Comment: When you say `if account.id == id:`, what does the second id mean? Is that referring to user input that asks the user which account they would like to access? Otherwise, thanks for your help but that one part confuses me.

Comment: `id` is the argument passed to `get_account()`.  You'd look up and account with, for example: `account_manager.get_account(5)` for the account with an id of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the user interface separated from the guts of the application, as ACEfanatic02 said.

Think about what an account has to have:

- a unique identifier
- a balance
- the (name of a) client
- a list of transactions

These are the instance attributes.

Also think about what it has to be able to do

- deposit money into the account
- withdraw from the account
- transfer to another account

These are the methods.

You might also want a way to print a text representation of the account. This can be done by providing the class with the magic method `__str__`.

A simple example:

```
def _checkamount(a):
    if a < 0:
        raise ValueError('amount must be >0')


class Account(object):

    maxnum = 0

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.balance = 0.0
        self.transactions = []
        Account.maxnum = Account.maxnum + 1
        self.number = Account.maxnum

    def __str__(self):
        "Generate a human-readable representation of the Account."
        rv = 'Accountnumber: ' + str(self.number) + '\n'
        rv += 'Client: ' + str(self.client) + '\n'
        rv += 'Balance: ' + str(self.balance) + '\n'
        return rv

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        _checkamount(amount)
        if self.balance < amount:
            raise ValueError('overdraft!')
        self.balance -= amount
        self.transactions.append(("withdraw", amount))

    def deposit(self, amount):
        _checkamount(amount)
        self.balance += amount
        self.transactions.append(("deposit", amount))

    def transfer(self, amount, other):
        _checkamount(amount)
        self.balance -= amount
        self.transactions.append(("transfer", amount, other.number))
        other.balance += amount
        other.transactions.append(("transfer", amount, self.number))
```

I saved this code in a file called `account.py`

An interactive test (using [Ipython](http://ipython.org/), highly recommended for interactive experimentation):

```
In [1]: from account import Account

In [2]: a = Account('myself')

In [3]: b = Account('someoneelse')

In [4]: a.deposit(200)

In [5]: a.withdraw(10)

In [6]: b.deposit(50)

In [7]: a.transfer(25, b)

In [8]: print a.transactions
[('deposit', 200), ('withdraw', 10), ('transfer', 25, 2)]

In [9]: print b
Accountnumber: 2
Client: someoneelse
Balance: 75.0

In [10]: print b.transactions
[('deposit', 50), ('transfer', 25, 1)]

In [11]: print a
Accountnumber: 1
Client: myself
Balance: 165.0

In [12]: a.withdraw(1000)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ffc10f6333fe> in <module>()
----> 1 a.withdraw(1000)

/home/rsmith/tmp/account.py in withdraw(self, amount)
     24         _checkamount(amount)
     25         if self.balance < amount:
---> 26             raise ValueError('overdraft!')
     27         self.balance -= amount
     28         self.transactions.append(("withdraw", amount))

ValueError: overdraft!
```

In this test I'm using a string as the `client`. Due to the dynamic nature of Python, I can later change this to e.g. a `Client` class, and the code would still work provided that Client has a `__str__` method.